# Auto resize image base on query string (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app built in Nodejs + Express for blog, domain is example.com.
I have some image on server, for example: example.com/image.png. This image is size 3MB, dimension: 3000 x 3000.

What I want is when client-side request the image url with query width, height: http://example.com/image.png?w=100&h=100.

I can't find any library do this for nodejs. Is there any advice?